# Currency Format

Tags: c#, .net

Please help me to build my own function for the currency format:

I've made here a function for `addPadding`, now I need a `formatCurrency` method.

This is the example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(addPadding("2567675432", 18, "R", "*"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static String addPadding(String strInputString, int iScale, String strDirection, String strPaddingCharacter)
    {
        String strReturnValue = strInputString;
        if (strInputString.Length < iScale)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i< iScale - strInputString.Length; i++)
            {
                if (strDirection == "R") strReturnValue += strPaddingCharacter;
                if (strDirection == "L") strReturnValue = strPaddingCharacter + strReturnValue;
                if (strReturnValue.Length == iScale) break;
            }
        }
        return strReturnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, change the Codes as Codes in your question.

Comment: Why can't you use the built in functionality? And please decide what you are using - C#, javascript or java (since you tagged your question with eclipse, it is not clear).

Comment: Putting your email in a post isn't a good idea, as it's a sure way to get loads of spam.

Comment: It's best practice to tell us what's going wrong with your approach.